# What are the premises and conclusion of the Functionalist claim that "matter doesn't matter"?

Tags: logic, argumentation, functionalism

I'm referring to the logical framework (the premises and conclusion) of the Functionalist argument that claims that two entities with indistinguishable **inputs and outputs** are the same thing, "matter doesn't matter," and etc.

Comment: Functionalism is not a "logical framework" and "matter doesn't matter" is not the conclusion of an argument. It is an approach consisting in studying just those aspects of phenomena for which matter doesn't matter and only structure/function does. Arguments for a particular aspect being of this sort depend on the aspect in question. For mental states, for example, you can read them in [Wikipedia's functionalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functionalism_(philosophy_of_mind)).